# Convert textarea row/column to screen x/y coordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I have a textarea element on my webpage that will contain some plain text (alphanumerics, newlines, tabs, spaces). I know how to get the row and column of my cursor. But, I need a way to convert those into screen coordinates so I could display a floating div at that exact location of the cursor. I see two ways

Method 1: Take the offset of the textarea from (0,0) on screen. For x-coord, iterate through each character on that line and multiply the number of characters with the width of each character (tabs vs actual characters would be counted differently) and add it to the original offset. For y-coord, take the number of rows times the height of each row and add it to the original offset. But, how do I compute the character width and row height?

Method 2: Find a javascript library. Does anybody know of an existing javascript library/framework such as jQuery that would do this? I have looked and can't seem to find anything.

Comment: when do you need to display this? after a click, or all the time?

Comment: When the user makes a change to the text within the textarea element, i need to display a floating div right where the text was changed. I know how to capture the text change event and i know the cursor location within the textarea. But, I need actual screen x/y coords to position the div.

Answer (score 0):

After the `onchange` event is fired, check for `mouseMove` events and then get the coordinates:

```
var waiting;
function text_changed(event) { //attach this to onChange
     waiting = true;
     setTimeout('waiting = false',1000);
}
function mouse_moved(event) { //attach this to mouseMove
    if (waiting) {
        display_div(event.pageX,event.pageY);
        waiting = false;
    }
}
function display_div(x,y) {
    $('#floating_div').css('left',x).css('top',y).css('display','block');
}
```

if you have to, replace the jQuery with regular DOM scripting:

```
function display_div(x,y) {
    var elmt = document.getElementById('floating_div');
    elmnt.setAttribute('style','left:'+x+';top:'+y+';display:block');
}
```

Comment: The textarea element has a onChange event but I don't believe it has the screenX and screenY attributes you listed here. Am I missing something in the text_changed function? Where are you getting that from?

Comment: @user554017 bind that to window or the parent element of textarea (if you can)

Comment: @SomekidwithHTML I will need to try this out. I am thinking that the mouse coordinates may not be equal to the cursor position. I will get back on this soon.

Comment: @Shaheer the parent element of the textarea is just a div. Not sure how that would help. Can you elaborate?